# keycloak admin cli unable to authenticate

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, keycloak

I am new to keycloak. I have been following the [admin cli guide](https://keycloak.gitbooks.io/documentation/server_admin/topics/admin-cli.html)  to automate realm creation ( inside a dockerfile ). The kcadm call to create realm is failing with authentication error - "*HTTP error - 401 Unauthorized*".

These are the 3 lines which I am trying to execute and the exception is thrown at the last line -

i) $JBOSS_HOME/bin/add-user-keycloak.sh -r master -u uadmin -p ${UADMIN_PWD}

( started the keycloak server after this )

ii) $JBOSS_HOME/bin/kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master -user uadmin --password ${UADMIN_PWD}

iii)  $JBOSS_HOME/bin/kcadm.sh create realms -s realm=myrealm -s enabled=true

Top of the stack is here -

```
04:53:48,721 ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-1) RESTEASY002005: 
Failed executing POST /admin/realms:org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnauthorizedException: Bearer
at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.AdminRoot.authenticateRealmAdminRequest(AdminRoot.java:160)
    at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.AdminRoot.getRealmsAdmin(AdminRoot.java:209)
```

I inspected the $HOME/.keycloak/kcadm.config file and the content is as below -

```
$ cat kcadm.config
{
  "serverUrl" : "http://localhost:8080/auth",
  "realm" : "master",
  "endpoints" : { }
}
```

There is no authentication token , which I could see there.

( One more observation, the "config credentials" command does not throw any exception if an invalid credential is passed. It would be helpful if there is an exception thrown. )

Any pointers for what am I doing wrong here, for the authentication issue during realm creation ?

Comment: I ran into the same issue. Do you mind posting your solution if you had one? Thanks.

Comment: Well mine was simply a typo error. If you notice carefully in the 2nd command I have written " -user uadmin" . It should be " --user uadmin" ( notice the '-' twice before user arg).

Comment: @Rajesh Ideally, you should answer your own question and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there was a typo error in the command --

"ii) $JBOSS_HOME/bin/kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080/auth --realm master -user uadmin --password ${UADMIN_PWD} "

The user parameter was "-user" , which should have been "--user"